# Automatically garbage text added in body and add that text at start of SQL query

Tags: php, php-7

I want try to execute my query in PHP 7

```
$sql ="SELECT * from order_details where order_id = '".$order_number."' 
     AND product_id=".$pro['pruduct_id'].";

$select = mysqli_query($connection,trim($sql)) or die("Query(Get Shipments) is not executed.");
```

I got following type of string at the start of SQL query and my sql query is not execute due to added that kind of string. I have also used `trim()` and string replace function but SQL query is not execute.

[image]

Comment: There's definitely a syntax error in there ... I think that final `."` on the query string is unnecessary. Would probably be have been avoided by using a prepared statement with bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That is becuase you have syntax error there

try this :

```
$sql ="SELECT * from order_details where order_id = '".$order_number."' AND product_id='".$pro['pruduct_id']."'";

$select = mysqli_query($connection, trim($sql)) or die("Query(Get Shipments) is not executed.");
```